# displaying validation errors in modal using codeIgniter and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I can't pass the validation errors in the modal, the form in the modal is submitting the data but instead of displaying it on top of the form, the validation errors are displaying on a separate plain page.

The validation errors are in a json_encode array. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image]

Controller: profile

```
public function get_fetchdata(){
    $Admin_id = $this->input->post('Admin_id');
    if(isset($Admin_id) and !empty($Admin_id)){
        $records = $this->profile_model->fetch_data($Admin_id);
        $output = '';
        foreach ($records->result_array() as $row) {                

            $output = '
            <div class="text-center" id="result"> </div>
            <form action="profile/profile_update" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Username </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" value='. $row["username"] .' placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" maxlength="10" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Email </label>
                <input type="Email" id="email" class="form-control" value='. $row["email"] .' placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" maxlength="20" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Phone Number </label>
                <input type="number" id="contact" class="form-control" value='.$row["contact"].' placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="contact" maxlength="11" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Password (6 characters minimum) </label>
                <input type="password" id="hoax" class="form-control" value='. $row["hoax"].' placeholder="Enter Password" name="hoax" maxlength="15" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Confirm Password (6 characters minimum) </label>
                <input type="password" id="confirm" class="form-control" value='.$row["hoax"].' placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm" maxlength="15" required>
              </div>
              
              <input type="hidden" id="Admin_id" class="form-control" value='. $row["Admin_id"] .' name="Admin_id">
              <input type="hidden" id="date" class="form-control" value='. $row["date_modified"] .' name="date">

              <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="1" type="submit" >Save</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger mx-2 float-right" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"> Cancel </button> 
              </form>';
            
        }
        echo $output;
    }else {
        echo "Nothing to show";
    }
}

public function profile_update(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[13]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'trim|required|min_length[11]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hoax', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm', 'ConfirmPassword', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
    
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>false, "profile_errors"=>validation_errors()));
        //redirect('mainNav/dashboard');
     }else{
        
        $this->profile_model->update_data();
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>true, "message"=>"Profile Successfully Updated"));
        //redirect('mainNav/dashboard');
     }  
}
```

modal in the view:

```
<div class="modal" id="Profile_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" >
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
    <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Profile</h5>
    <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span class="text-white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" >
    <!-- <div class="text-center" id="result"> </div> -->
    <div id="data_profile"> </div> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
$('.profile').click(function(){
                    var Admin_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('profile/get_fetchdata'); ?>" ,
                        method:"POST",
                        data: {Admin_id:Admin_id},
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#data_profile').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
                
                $('#login_form').submit(function(  ){
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    var Admin_id = $('#Admin_id').val();
                    var username = $('#username').val();
                    var email    = $('#email').val();
                    var contact  = $('#contact').val();
                    var hoax     = $('#hoax').val();
                    var confirm  = $('#confirm').val();
                    var date     = $('#date').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('profile/profile_update'); ?>",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {Admin_id:Admin_id, username:username, email:email, contact:contact, confirm:confirm, date:date, hoax:hoax},
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function(data){
                            if (data.result){
                                $('#adminId').val("");
                                $('#username').val("");
                                $('#email').val("");
                                $('#contact').val("");
                                $('#hoax').val("");
                                $('#confirm').val("");
                                $('#date').val("");
                                $('#result').html('<p class="alert-success"> ' + data.message + ' </p>');
                            }else{
                                $('#result').html('<p class="alert-warning"> ' + data.profile_errors + ' </p>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: does your page get refresh when you submit form ? and why you have commented `event.preventDefault();` this line ?

Comment: @Swati the page is not refreshed, but transfer to a plain page, and the event.preventDefault(); is not working, I wonder if I change the location it could fix the problem.

Comment: `#result` is commented in the model. You may have another `#result` element in the page. Is this the problem ?

Comment: yes ... I tried to put div in the modal and in the echo but nothing works. the validation errors in JSON have still redirected me to another page